# Homotopy equivalent space satisfies the same cover property whose covers are contractible.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $A$ be a topological space which has the property that it admits an open cover by open subsets
$U_i$, $i=1,2,\cdots, 5$ such that for every $i$ the inclusion $U_i\to A$ is homotopic to a constant map. Let $B$ be a topological space which is homotopy-equivalent to $A$. Then $B$ has the same above property.

I guess homotopytype preserves the holes in each space we can intuitively see the property is preserved but I can't properly show the existence of the cover for $B$ and then each open set in $B$ are contractible.

Answer (score 1):

Fix inverse homotopy equivalences $f:B\rightarrow A$ and $g:A\rightarrow B$ (actually we only need that $g\circ f\simeq id_B$). For $i=1,\dots,n$ put
$$V_i=f^{-1}(U_i).$$
This set is open by the continuity of $f$. Because $id_B\simeq g\circ f$, we see that up to homotopy the inclusion $V_i\hookrightarrow B$ factors as
$$V_i=f^{-1}(U_i)\xrightarrow f U_i\hookrightarrow A\xrightarrow gB$$
and this composite is null-homotopic, since the inclusion $U_i\hookrightarrow A$ is.